# What's the difference between calling Firebase's updateProfile method versus updating Firebase's real-time database to render a profile photo?

Tags: reactjs, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, firebase-authentication

As a background, I am using Firebase Authentication to create users using Firebase's createUserWithEmailAndPassword method. During sign-up, I use Firebase's updateProfile method to provide it a photoURL and also store the photoURL as user information in Firebase's real-time database using their UID. When I am rendering these user profiles, I am rendering the user data from Firebase's real-time database.

After the creation of the user, I want to allow the user to update their profile photos. Now, here's where I'm confused.

When updating the user's profile photos, what is the difference between merely updating the photoURL in the user profile in Firebase's real-time database? Versus calling Firebase's updateProfile method? I don't quite understand what the updateProfile method is doing in respect to the real-time database.

I am rather new to the world of React and Firebase so forgive me if I am unclear, I will try and best clarify what I mean.

Answer (score 1):

`updateProfile` is doing nothing with respect to Realtime Database.  Updating the profile just modifies the user account in Firebase Authentication.  If you also want to record a profile URL in Realtime Database, that will be a separate operation.  The URL is not automatically linked between the two products in any way.

Comment: Thanks for clarifying that, Doug! For what I'm trying to do, is there a best practice method? For example, is it better to keep track of the profile photos in the Firebase Authentication and render based off my authentication? Or to keep track of the profile photos in the Realtime database and render what's in the database?

Comment: There is no best practice.  It depends on what you need to do.  If you need one user to be able to know another user's profile URL, there is no Firebase Auth API that will expose that.  You would have to use some other storage for that.  But if a user can only see their own URL, then you don't need to store it elsewhere.

Comment: Thank you very much, Doug. I understand now!

Comment: If this answer was helpful, please upvote it and accept it as correct.